# Get object value outside of class?

Tags: python, class, object, time, global

I have a program that tracks the time passed since the start of the instance using `time()` inside a class.

I want to write a function that calculates a high score using the time, outside of the class. Is there a way to access the time from outside the object without making the time global? The time has to be calculated inside the class.

Comment: You need to show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for -- does this work?

```
import time

class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()

    def get_time_elapsed(self):
        return time.time() - self.start_time

m = MyObj()
print m.get_time_elapsed()
```